# templateUrl angularjs routerProvider for Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm new in angularjs. How to pass my templateUrl routerProvider angularjs in my Codeigniter application.

For example my codeigniter controller is:

```
class Tester extends CI_Controller {
  function __contruct();
  {
     parent::__contruct();
  }

  function index()
  {
     $this->load->model('m_tester');
     $data['title'] = 'Home';
     $this->load->view('tester/template',$data);
  }
}
```

and here is my controller to create my json data, still in one controller file:

```
function studentlist()
{
  $this->load->model(array('m_tester'));
  $data = $this->m_tester->studentlist();
  $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

the json output is work well when I access my page in  because my homepage for tester page is to display studentlist() controller without routerProvider.

and here is my view folder and file in codeigniter:

```
cbt
-application
--views
---tester
```

I have menu file in views tester folder, it's menu.php:

```
switch($title)
{
  case 'Home';
  include 'home.php';
  break;
}
```

so my question is how to pass my templateUrl in my angularjs routerProvider config for my codeigniter?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routerProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routerProvider
    .when('/', {
       templateUrl: '**<--I'M STILL CONFUSED HERE-->**',
       controller: 'studentController'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: where does the `templateUrl` come from?

Comment: Are you trying to use 'tester/template'?

Comment: @Oki : templateUrl in my app.js

Comment: @Christian : I'm not sure about tester/template because template is my basic file for template, included header, body and footer... or should I change my file structure?

Comment: @Agung If what you want is to display that test file, then you would use that. If what you want is to display a segment of that file, you should break it up into pieces.

Comment: @Christian : OK, you're right, thanks for the advice, I'll try... and maybe found a new way

Comment: @Agung Are you using any controller in your angular app? Angular app needs a controller afaik

Comment: @Christian yes, sure. I have created my angular controller to get my data from database and then pass in my contrller and display in my tester home page